# Best way to convert Integer to print a String

Tags: java, integer, constants

I have a small and probably stupid question. I'm unsure how to navigate this. I want to figure out how to convert an Integer in order to print out a String like in the unit test below. **I'm NOT allowed to use an enum**, as exact question asks for it to be represented as an integer. Do I need a HashMap, or just simple switch statements? When I run the unit test, I need it to print out:

```
Cat (Ragdoll: House Cat) is 1 year old, is 30 units fast.
```

but it's currently printing out:

```
Cat (Ragdoll: 3) is 1 year old, is 30 units fast.
```

**Cat Class** (I removed unrelated methods):

```
public class Cat extends Animal { 


    private Integer type;
    private String breed;

    static final Integer LION = 1;
    static final Integer TIGER = 2;
    static final Integer HOUSE_CAT = 3;
    static final Integer PUMA = 4;


    public Cat(int age, int speed, Integer type, String breed){
        super(age, speed);
        this.type = type;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Cat (" + breed + ": " + type + ")" + super.toString());

    }

}
```

**The unit tests** (can use enums in Dog class so no issues with it).

```
@Test
    void testAllParts() {
        Animal dog = new Dog(12, 30, Dog.type.GUNDOG, "Irish Setter");
        Animal cat = new Cat(1, 30, Cat.HOUSE_CAT, "Ragdoll");
        
        assertTrue(dog.isOlder(cat));
        assertFalse(cat.isOlder(dog));
        
        assertFalse(dog.isFaster(cat));
        assertFalse(cat.isFaster(dog));
        
        assertEquals("Dog (Irish Setter: GUNDOG) is 12 years old, is 30 units fast.", dog.toString());
        assertEquals("Cat (Ragdoll: House Cat) is 1 year old, is 30 units fast.", cat.toString());
        
        assertFalse(dog.equals(cat));
        
        Animal [] a = dog.multiply(2);
        assertEquals(a[0], a[1]);
        assertFalse(dog.equals(a[0]));
        assertEquals(2, a.length);
        
        a = cat.multiply(2);
        assertEquals(a[0], a[1]);
        assertFalse(cat.equals(a[0]));
        assertEquals(2, a.length);
        
    }
```

Comment: Do not use integer constans. Learn about [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: To better help myself ask/answer/review questions, why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: You could use an array of String's: ``String[] CAT_TYPES = new String[] {"Lion", "Tiger", House Cat", "Puma"};``

Comment: The down-votes may be related to "I'm NOT allowed to use an enum" with no further explanation as to why you should avoid the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `enum` would be the obvious choice here, but since you state you can't use them, you could use a `Map` from the value to the name:

```java
private static final Map<Integer, String> TYPES = 
    Map.of(1, "Lion",
           2, "Tiger",
           3, "House cat",
           4, "Puma");
```

And then use it in the `toString` method:

```java
public String toString() {
    return ("Cat (" + breed + ": " + TYPES.get(type) + ")" + super.toString());
}
```